# Error: avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt X of 10: not in sync: resp=

Tags: arduino, avr, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, avrdude

I am using an Arduino Uno and every time I upload the code I get this error:

`Error: avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt X of 10: not in sync: resp=`

I have lookad at every single possible option; first of all, the Arduino is not damaged; I made sure. I did the following :

- checked the port
- tried the following programmers: ArduinoISP, AVRISP, AVRISPmkll
- tried changing the board from the toolbar, tried Arduino Uno, Arduino Mega, etc.
- tried more than one USB cable
- tried on 2 PCs
- tried installing different versions of Arduino
- tried to press on burn bootloader option in the toolbar (that I didn't know what it could do exactly)
- restart pc, restart Arduino IDE, reset Arduino, reset Arduino when RX led lights up.

I am a newbie with Arduino, so I would be grateful if you could explain in detail, and please don't ignore because this problem is going to drive me crazy and I don't know anyone that I can consult.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won

Comment: checked this one already , didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are custom/forged Arduino boards where the reset is not by default connected to the reset from the (on-board) programmer. You can try pressing upload, and pressing the reset button on the Arduino at the same time (and release it shortly after). If this works, then you can likely find two solder pads close together without a connection between them. Connecting them would re-attach the auto reset (disconnecting them can be useful if you don't want users to be able to reflash your microprocessor). Alternatively, it might be possible that you have bought an Arduino without a bootloader. In that case you will have to upload the bootloader through another Arduino board using ArduinoISP as explained [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/ArduinoISP).